# can't write unknown attribute `html` Trace of template inclusion

Tags: ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting a weird error in my ROR APP. I attached my `_form.html.erb`file since this is where the browser says my error is. I am a beginner so not really sure what I am doing wrong in this instance. thanks!

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">
 <h1>New Review</h1>
 </div>

<%= form_for(@lawfirm, @review) do |f| %>
  <% if @review.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@review.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this review from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @review.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>

    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :rating %>
    <%= f.number_field :rating, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :comment %>
    <%= f.text_area :comment, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

here is my stack trace:

```
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/attribute.rb:138:in `with_value_from_database'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:39:in `write_from_user'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:74:in `write_attribute_with_type_cast'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:56:in `write_attribute'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:96:in `write_attribute'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:373:in `[]='
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:424:in `form_for'
app/views/reviews/_form.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_reviews__form_html_erb___829028679_68515284'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
app/views/reviews/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_reviews_new_html_erb___645944526_88267872'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:815:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
Request

Parameters:

{"lawfirm_id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Full stack trace would be more useful. Can't see anything wrong with this partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be here:

```
form_for(@lawfirm, @review)
```

The proper syntax for a nested resource in a form is:

```
form_for([@lawfirm, @review])
```

`form_for` expects only the first argument to be the resource (a nested resource in this case). The second argument would be a hash of options of which `html` is one of the supported option keys. This may be causing the error down the stack.